# What does this message from syslog@localhost signifies?

Tags: unix, linux-kernel, syslog, syslog-ng

```
Message from syslogd@saskappcu at Mar 18 13:24:54 ...
 kernel:BUG: soft lockup - CPU#30 stuck for 61s! [events/30:161]

Message from syslogd@saskappcu at Mar 18 13:24:54 ...
 kernel:Process events/30 (pid: 161, ti=f4ea4000 task=f4e5faa0 task.ti=f4ea4000)

Message from syslogd@saskappcu at Mar 18 13:24:54 ...
 kernel:Stack:

Message from syslogd@saskappcu at Mar 18 13:24:54 ...
 kernel:Call Trace:

Message from syslogd@saskappcu at Mar 18 13:24:54 ...
 kernel:Code: 00 89 51 04 89 0a 89 43 20 89 43 24 8b 43 08 39 d8 74 23 83 40 7c 01 31 c9 8b 7b 0c 8b 15 58 09 ac c0 8b 02 39 c2 75 09 eb 31 90 <8b> 00 39 d0 74 2a 3b 78 0c 75 f5 89 d8 ba 00 00 04 00 e8 b9 a0

Message from syslogd@saskappcu at Mar 18 13:24:58 ...
 kernel:BUG: soft lockup - CPU#8 stuck for 61s! [buildop:2223]

Message from syslogd@saskappcu at Mar 18 13:24:58 ...
 kernel:Process buildop (pid: 2223, ti=e9724000 task=f3ba0aa0 task.ti=e9724000)

Message from syslogd@saskappcu at Mar 18 13:24:58 ...
 kernel:Stack:

Message from syslogd@saskappcu at Mar 18 13:24:58 ...
 kernel:Call Trace:

Message from syslogd@saskappcu at Mar 18 13:24:58 ...
 kernel:Code: 26 00 89 c8 f0 81 28 00 00 00 01 74 05 e8 2c fe ff ff c3 8d b4 26 00 00 00 00 66 ba 00 01 f0 66 0f c1 10 38 f2 74 0e f3 90 8a 10 <eb> f6 66 83 38 00 75 f4 eb e5 c3 8d 74 26 00 f0 81 28 00 00 00
```

Comment: Obviously, message means soft lockup detected. You can google for what that mean. If you want to debug this problem by youself (and ask as to help with that), you need to provide additional information. If you want someone else to debug, you need to ask maintainers for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A **softlockup** is defined as a bug that causes the kernel to loop in
>   kernel mode for more than 20 seconds without giving other tasks a chance to run.

The log

```
kernel:BUG: soft lockup - CPU#30 stuck for 61s! [events/30:161]
```

is generated by the following line in [`kernel/kernel/watchdog.c`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/watchdog.c#L469)

```
pr_emerg("BUG: soft lockup - CPU#%d stuck for %us! [%s:%d]\n",
         smp_processor_id(),
         duration,
         current->comm,
         task_pid_nr(current));
```

It means that

- The `CPU core 30` in the system,
- has been busy executing kernel code for the past 61 seconds.
- The current thread on the system being `events/30`,
- whose process-id is `161`.

---

For more details, checkout **[`kernel/Documentation/lockup-watchdogs.txt`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/lockup-watchdogs.txt)**.